# After moving state, clearing the state affects the other state

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-redux

I am new to ngrx and I have a problem with unsubscribing. I am using both the latest versions of Angular and ngrx.

I have CreateState and ModelState. After creating CreateState within a dialogue, I want to copy CreateState to be part of ModelState and then clearing CreateState so the dialogue becomes empty.

For this, I am first receiving the whole state of CreateState and then calling an Action of ModelState for copying.

```
this.store$.select(CreateSelectors.selectCreateState).subscribe((state: CreateState.State) => {
  this.store$.dispatch(new ModelActions.CreateAction(state));
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/canvas');
});
```

After I moved to the new page, I am calling an action on CreateState for clearing.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CreateActions.ClearAction());
}
```

But it seems that the Select Subscription from my first page is still listening, so clearing the CreateState fires the select and again dispatches the ModelActions.CreateAction.

I tried listening just for the `.first()` Observable or unsubscribing from the Observable but Typescript says there is no function for `.first()` or `.unsubscribe()`.

Am I getting something wrong? Should I use a different approach for moving and clearing states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should run your Code through a pipe, there you can use the first() operator.

```
this.store$.select(CreateSelectors.selectCreateState).pipe(
first(), // should unsubscribe after first iteration
tap( (state: CreateState) => {
      this.store$.dispatch(new ModelActions.CreateAction(state));
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/canvas');
})
).subscribe();
```

Or you could set a variable and subscribe to it.

```
const subscription = this.store$.select(CreateSelectors.selectCreateState).pipe(
tap( (state: CreateState) => {
      this.store$.dispatch(new ModelActions.CreateAction(state));
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/canvas');
})
);

// if you don't subscribe nothing will happen
// unsubscribes after first iteration
subscription.first().subscribe();
```

some documentation:

live demo of [first()](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bw5byu?file=index.ts)

documentation of first() [RxJS Documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) [learn-rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for a solution for hours... Could you please tell when I have to use `.pipe`?

Comment: everytime you want to manipulate the data from the observable you should use `.pipe()`. if you only want to assign the value from the observable then subscribe immediately to it. and use it for cases like `.subscribe( data => this.name = data )`

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Is this a new thing? Because I didn't need `.pipe()` before when I used `.debounceTime()`, `.distinctUntilChanged()` or else...

Comment: I am not sure anymore as there are so many breaking changes in rxjs but I think it was with rxjs 4 to 5

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe to the observable that returns from the select-function.
You need to store that observable in an variable, so that you can refer to it.

Then you can use that variable to unsubscribe from